# How the custom the ActionBar by using xml in Android?

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar

I am try to custom the `ActionBar` by using xml in Android.

The `actionbat.xml` is like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bar_background" >

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/bar_icon"/>    

</RelativeLayout >
```

And I using the following code to set `ActionBar` in `Fragment`

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.function_list, container, false) ;

        ActionBar bar = getActivity().getActionBar();
        bar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);
```

But the ActionBar didn't change anything , did I missing something ?

---------------------------EDIT------------------------------

I have try `getSupportActionBar`, but it show The method getSupportActionBar() is undefined for the type Activity.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this

```
    View view=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.vw_custom_action_bar, null);
    ActionBar actionBar=getActivity().getSuppotedActionBar() // for ActionBarActivity

   //ActionBar actionBar=getActivity().getActionBar() // for Fragmentactivity
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setCustomView(view);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.function_list, container, false) ;
ActionBar bar = getActivity().getSuppotedActionBar();
bar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);
```

Comment: I have try , but it show `The method getSuppotedActionBar() is undefined for the type Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not able to access the activity in `onCreateView()`. Try this in `onActivityCreated()`.

Answer (score 0):

For this you should have an activity that extends ActionbarActivity and that activity have fragments.inside your activity do below code -

```
    actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
    mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    actionbar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionbar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    actionbar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionbar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
    actionbar.setCustomView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.actionbar, null),
            new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
                    ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    Gravity.CENTER
            )
    );
    mImageView = (ImageView) actionbar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.image_view);
```

hope this answer helpfull for you.

Comment: I have try getSupportActionBar  , but it show The method getSupportActionBar() is undefined for the type Activity.

Comment: for this you have to add support library "android-support-v7-appcompat" you can import it from your sdk path.Go to folder where sdk is install and search for folser - extras/android/support and import v7 to your build path.

Answer (score 0):

But wait.
what you are asking to say is very bad.
The fragment should not know it's activity like this.

you should do something like that:

Fragment:

```
void onAttach(Activity activity){
parent = (MyFragmentListener) activity;
}

void onActivityCreated(Bundle b){
    parent.askToDoSomethingSpecial();
}
```

Activity implements MyFragmentListener:

```
void askToDoSomethingSpecial(){
getActionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);
// or getSupportedActionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to set custom **Actionbar** in **Android**, All you need to do is:-

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
LayoutInflater inf = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View v = inf.inflate(R.layout.custom_tv, null);       //**custom_tv is layout for actionbar**
((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(title);               

getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(v);
```

/*
* Use this if you are working with **fragment**
* `getActivity().getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);`
*/

Thats it. Hope this helps.